# get .csv file content primefaces fileuploader

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am having primefaces fileUpload with fileUploadListener.
I am going to upload only .csv files and i need to parse them.

Is it possible to do in fileUploadListener?
I would like to take line by line....

Comment: Why don't you get the entire file and then parse it to a class to process it line by line?

Comment: I am trying to do something like this
[code]
InputStream inp;
  
  String test = "";
  try {
   inp = event.getFile().getInputstream();
   
   int read = 0;
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
   
   while ((read = inp.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    String temp = new String(bytes);
    test += temp;
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
[/code]
but test does not have entire text at the end...

Comment: this is something that works, now i need only to parse it....

InputStream inp;inp = event.getFile().getInputstream();
  try {  
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Destination.csv"));  
         int length = 0;  
         byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) event.getFile().getSize()];  
         while ((length = inp.read(bytes)) != -1) {  
             out.write(bytes, 0, length);  
         }  
         inp.close();  
         out.flush();  
         out.close();
                  
     } catch (IOException e) {  
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
     }

Comment: Edit your question to put the code.